# Аналогия MODE(DOS) для Linux, или как улучшить терминал

Tags: linux, консоль

есть интересный вопрос. По умолчанию в Linux идёт стандартный терминал (схожий с 80x25) знаков, в серверной Ubuntu этот размер весьма и весьма шире. Не подскажите как на того-же AlmaLinux поставить это улучшение экрана? И как настроить?

Как сейчас:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочется вот так вот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то я не очень понял, что конкретно вы хотите. Хотите чтобы влезало больше текста — поставьте разрешение, родное для монитора, и выберите шрифт помельче. Хотите иметь несколько терминалов в одном — вон прямо на скриншоте внизу написано, что это называется byobu

Comment: @andreyma Да, я именно хочу что-бы влезло больше текста. Что-бы поместилось больше "раздельных окон" я использую `screen`. В чём прикол, я использую чистые сообщения от zabbix на 2м экране. но так как я сменил ubuntu на alma, мне ну очень нахватает старого разрешения консоли. Я уверен что драйвер или апп решает мою проблему.

Comment: Разрешение экрана в текстовом режиме зависит от видеокарты, от драйвера к ней, от режима загрузки этого драйвера (включен ли Kernel Mode Setting или нет) и от режима загрузки самой системы (BIOS или UEFI, в режиме UEFI разрешение экрана может унаследоваться из настроек прошивки), а также от загрузчика (например GRUB может менять разрешение в соответствии со своими настройками) — в общем вот это вот всё нужно копать, чтобы разобраться, что делать с разрешением экрана в вашем конкретном случае

Comment: (а ещё на всякий случай хочу обратить внимание, что на втором скриншоте не стандартный терминал, а графический режим и запущенный в нём GNOME Terminal, так что получить идентичную картинку в стандартном терминале вы не сможете как минимум банально по причине отсутствия векторных шрифтов и поддержки 24-битных цветов)

Comment: @andreymal Я не уверен что вы видели Ubuntu Server, я сисадмин, всегда носил в кармане монитор 1024х768"6.  На каждом Ubuntu терминале разрешение char-to-place выглядит офигеть как лучше чем на стандартном. И ппц, IT директор сказал что надо переходить на AlmaLinux, тут я бессилен, но хочу так-же как было в Ubuntu Server.

Comment: Конечно видел, вот у меня прямо сейчас один из экземпляров Ubuntu Server в запущен в виртуалке и выглядит так https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Jrx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на мой вопрос лежит вот в этой статье.

- https://linuxhint.com/set_screen_resolution_linux_kernel_boot/

Оказывается разрешение экрана меняется при перенастройке файла конфигурации GRUB.